# deja backup: UnicodeDecodeError "unexpected end of data"

Tags: backup, ubuntu-12.04, duplicity

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and deja backup.

It encounters an error during the preparation of the backup:

```
Backup failed: unknown reason:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/selection.py", line 187, in Iterate
log.Debug(_("Selecting %s") % subpath.name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 48: unexpected end of data
```

see Below for the full report.

I suspect this is because a filename was not encoded correctly.

Do you have an idea how to correct for this, or at least make deja backup ignore the problem?

Thank you!

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1403, in <module>
with_tempdir(main)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1396, in with_tempdir
fn()
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1366, in main
full_backup(col_stats)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 491, in full_backup
bytes_written = dummy_backup(tarblock_iter)
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 197, in dummy_backup
while tarblock_iter.next():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/diffdir.py", line 507, in next
result = self.process(self.input_iter.next(), size)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/diffdir.py", line 188, in get_delta_iter
for new_path, sig_path in collated:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/diffdir.py", line 281, in collate2iters
for relem1 in riter1:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/selection.py", line 187, in Iterate
log.Debug(_("Selecting %s") % subpath.name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 48: unexpected end of data
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a workaround,

You can change the session language before call to duplicity

```
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

It work for me, my default LANG is "es_ES.UTF-8", and duplicity fails. With "en_US.UTF-8" works.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1050509